# Spritesheet animation easeljs-0.7.1.min.js

Tags: html, animation, easeljs, sprite-sheet

I am trying to make a spritesheet animation that keeps on looping but there is going something wrong in my code. the image doesn`t get displayed on the screen and still getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'move_obj' of null. could someone help me getting this fixed.

```
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    score = 0;

     var munt = new Image();
     munt.src = "imgs/sprite.png"; 
     munt.onload = Tiltie;

}

function Tiltie(event){

    var munt = event.target;
    var container = new createjs.Container();
    stage.addChild(container);

    var spriteSheet  =  new createjs.SpriteSheet(
        munt, //image to use
        100, //width of each sprite
        100, //height of each sprite
        {   
            move_obj: [0, 9]
        });


    bmpSeq = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(spriteSheet);

    bmpSeq.regX = bmpSeq.spriteSheet.frameWidth/2|0;
    bmpSeq.regY = bmpSeq.spriteSheet.frameHeight / 2 | 0;

    bmpSeq.gotoAndPlay("move_obj");

    bmpSeq.currentFrame = 0;
    stage.addChild(bmpSeq);



    Ticker.addListener(window);
    // Best Framerate targeted (60 FPS)
    Ticker.setInterval(17);
}
```

Comment: What version of CreateJS as you using? This code looks fairly old, and a few of your approaches were deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Old Q :) Not very familiar with this version though, may I recommend using the new EaselJS v0.8.0+?
As for Spritesheet Animations, I've built a basic setup for EaselJS and all you'll have to do is declare a few parameters and you're done.
Also, my setup uses some new extra libraries from EaselJS which offer support for WebGL including a few fixes, [check it out here](https://github.com/catalinberta/SpriteAnim)

Let me know if you need any assistance, cheers